# I get an aws s3 NoSuchKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The aws s3 bucket settings and permissions are perfect. But when I click the url received from the server, I get this error.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>1.jpg</Key>
<RequestId>...</RequestId>
<HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here is my IAM user setup:
[image]

It also lifted public access blocks on buckets. (Currently in public state)

Here are my bucket permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my bucket name/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::awsaccount ID:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my bucket name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course, I also set CORS settings.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ]
    }
]
```

I seem to have set everything appropriately, but when I upload an image, the image is not in the bucket.

What could be the problem?

How do I get through this difficulty?

i need help please

For reference, if you upload an image directly to the aws s3 bucket and check the object URL, it works normally.

What could be the problem?

How do I get through this difficulty?

i need help please

Comment: What does "the url received from the server" refer to? What server?

Comment: The environment is next.js + mongoDB.
The url returned by the server is: Ex) https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/nextjs-codingapple/me.png 
When I click this url, I get an error.

Comment: Some troubleshooting guidance [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/404-error-nosuchkey-s3).

Comment: The error is saying that the `nextjs-codingapple` bucket does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

thank you I solved this problem.
The cause was in my code. I forgot the image upload code.
I've only written code to request the aws s3 bucket path.